# Failing to install android studio due to HAXM error on windows

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to install android studio with the following custom installation:
[image]

However, I get the following error:

```
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Failed to install Intel HAXM. For details, please check the installation log: "C:\Users\Tal\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log2.txt"
Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows
Installer log is located at C:\Users\Tal\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log2.txt
Installer log contents:
=== Logging started: 1/22/2021  1:01:07 ===
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.
```

I read all over the internet and all solutions were to uncheck `Control panel -> Programs and features -> turn windows features on and off -> Hypver-v` and to enable VT-x via bios.

I did these steps both but yet to fail in the installation for same reason.

Here is where I've  enabled VT-x:
[image]

What more could I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows 7 use this version of Haxm driver or lower

https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/98257850/1c77134c-9f15-11e8-98ba-6f1342d09db8?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210115%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210115T002546Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=db9442a4615cf2cc10a4c0212837ef84100d577c03fdb2913297e9d506609fef&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=50022328&key_id=0&repo_id=98257850&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dhaxm-windows_v7_3_0.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream

also take a look at the resales versions https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/ and look for the version that suit your machine